# Check if 24 hour formatted hour is between 2 others, over 2 days

Tags: php, datetime

I have a datetime, obtained by getting current time and formatting it to my user's timezone. Let's say it's "18", for 6pm in 24 hour format.

I need to have a true/false returned when checking if it falls between 15h one day, and 10h the next day. Between 3pm and the next 10am.

My code so far looks like this, but I cant get PHP to understand that the end-hour is in the next day. What am I doing wrong?!

```
$deviceTZ = 'America/Toronto';
$dt = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone($deviceTZ));
$dt->setTimestamp(time());
$deviceTime = $dt->format('H');

$silentStart = 15;
$silentEnd = 10;
$silentStartDT = date_create_from_format('H', $silentStart);
$silentEndDT = date_create_from_format('H', $silentEnd);

if($silentStartDT > $silentEndDT)
{ $silentEndDT->modify('+1 day'); }

if (($deviceTime > $silentStartDT) && ($deviceTime < $silentEndDT))
{ echo "Silent Period"; }
else { echo "Not Silent"; }
```

Comment: You're just checking the hour.  Why not check YmdH

Comment: I only have access to the hour component, the frontend is already built (by someone else) and features a dropdown to select start time and end time, and it stores a number between 0 and 23 for each one (after checking that end time is indeed after the start time, to avoid broken timespans)

Comment: work in the opposite direction, add the input hour to a date, then check if that date/time falls within the date/time range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I may have come up with a solution

```
$deviceTime = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone($deviceTZ));
$silentStartDT = new DateTime($silentStart.":00");
$silentEndDT = (new DateTime($silentEnd.":00"))->modify('+1 day');

if($silentStart == 0 && $silentEnd == 0)
{ echo "No Silent Mode set."; }
else{
    if ($deviceTime >= $silentStartDT && $deviceTime <= $silentEndDT) 
    { echo "Within Range<br>"; }
}
```